# Two DialogActivity Overlap content in android

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have to require implement previous screen visible. So I used `DialogActivity` which have theme like

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"

In short, I have three screen,

```
Screen1- MainHomeScreen  -> Activity 
Screen2- ContentListScreen  -> DialogActivity 
Screen3- ContentDetailScreen  -> DialogActivity
```

Screen2.png
[image]

I found this wrong thing from screen 2 in Screen3

Screen3.png
[image]

Problem: App lunch `MainHomeScreen` then I launch `ContentListScreen` that is ok but My problem is When I launch `ContentDetailScreen` (Screen3) without finish `ContentListScreen` (Screen2), I found Screen3 overlapped on Screen2 means Screen2 content is visible in Screen3. I want to show only
Screen3 content at there like Activity does.

Screen 1 is Regular activity so I don't put any description for that screen here.

Screen 2 Description

```
<activity
    android:name=".ContentListDialogActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"

    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
</activity>
```

and in activity

```
public class ContentListDialogActivity extends BaseActivity {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_content_list);
    getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Screen 3 Description

```
<activity
    android:name=".ContentDetailsDialogActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
</activity>
```

and in activity

```
public class ContentDetailsDialogActivity extends BaseActivity {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_content_details);

    getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: can you add some screenshot of what you're saying *"Screen2 content is visible in Screen3"*

Comment: @AshishRanjan I have attached screenshot

Comment: you should close your screen2 by calling `ContentListDialogActivity.this.finish()` on the event when you're opening the screen3, which would be button click, i think.

Comment: Yes that's way we do it but I need screen2 when it back and preserve all thing which I put in Screen2 so. do you know any property that manage this things?

Comment: then you should hide the screen2 layout by using `yourMainLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` on the button click and set it back to View.VISIBLE again when needed.

Comment: That is not right thing to hide view after lunching screen3. Could you have another solution instead of invisible